# "%" character causing issues in IIS URL rewrite regex

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I'm replatforming an online shop, and part of that process is writing 301 redirects for old links customers may have bookmarked to hit their new addresses. All of them work apart from the ones in which the old address contains the `%` character. It seems to somehow be interfering with the regex. The rule is:

```
<rule name="Custom 41 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^c80/How-to-%20Use-Shop-Name\.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/how-to-use-shop-name" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Testing using the built in regex tester in IIS tells me that hitting

/c80/How-to-%20Use-Shop-Name.aspx

Matches the pattern, yet the rule fails to redirect me when I hit that address.

I should also stress that there are about 400 rewrites in my web.config, but only the 3 which contain the `%` character break.

Comment: What if you just use a regular space ` ` instead? Maybe the input string is interpreted as a URL-decoded string.

Comment: Grea, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the string that is tested against the regex is already Url-decoded, you no longer need the `%20` in your regex. Just use a plain space:

```
<match url="^c80/How-to- Use-Shop-Name\.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
```

Also, in case the space is optional, you may use a `?` after it:

```
<match url="^c80/How-to- ?Use-Shop-Name\.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. but it only works when %20 is In-Between. if %20 is at the last of the sentence then it does not work. Can you please help on it?

Comment: @Juhi You may match 0 or more whitespace with `\s*`. Put it anywhere in the pattern where spaces may occur.

Comment: My url is "http://staging.Temp.com/about-us/Optimization-Institute-+target/%20 but its not working

Comment: @Juhi Note that `+` is a special regex metacharacter and must be escaped with ``\``. And after escaping `+`, add `\s*` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: i tried with "staging.Temp.com/about-us/Optimization-Institute-\target/\s* but still same issue

Comment: @Juhi: Your input starts with `about`: see [`^about-us/Optimization-Institute-\+target/\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/EEhZK8/1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150391/discussion-between-juhi-and-wiktor-stribizew).